# How to change the pivot table style from default blue to other colors using apache-poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, pivot-table

When i create a pivot table using the below code, it comes with some default template style(blue). How to change this default style of pivot table using apache-poi library

```
pivotTable = sheet2.createPivotTable(aref, new CellReference("A4"), sheet1);
```

[What I want.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXYUm.png)

[What i am able to generate through code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJEYS.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`XXSPivotTable` is using named style `PivotStyleLight16` per default. See [setDefaultPivotTableDefinition](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_4_1_0/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFPivotTable.java?view=markup#l217).

There is no method for changing this in high level `XSSF` classes until now. Bu we can get the underlying low level `CTPivotTableStyle` form the `CTPivotTableDefinition` got via [XSSFPivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFPivotTable.html#getCTPivotTableDefinition--). Then we can use `CTPivotTableStyle.setName` to set another named style:

```
pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotTableStyleInfo().setName("PivotStyleMedium7");
```

Complete example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

class CreatePivotTableStyle {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xlsx") ) {

   Sheet pivotSheet = workbook.createSheet("Pivot");
   Sheet dataSheet = workbook.createSheet("Data");

   Row row;
   Cell cell;
   Object[][] data = new Object[][]{
    new Object[]{"Name", "Count"},
    new Object[]{"A", 2d},
    new Object[]{"B", 4d},
    new Object[]{"A", 1d},
    new Object[]{"B", 7d}
   };
   for (int r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
    row = dataSheet.createRow(r);
    Object[] rowData = data[r];
    for (int c = 0; c < rowData.length; c++) {
     cell = row.createCell(c);
     if (rowData[c] instanceof String) {
      cell.setCellValue((String)rowData[c]);
     } else if (rowData[c] instanceof Double) {
      cell.setCellValue((Double)rowData[c]);
     }
    }
   }

   AreaReference arerReference = new AreaReference("A1:B5", SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);

   XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = ((XSSFSheet)pivotSheet).createPivotTable(arerReference, new CellReference("A4"), dataSheet);

   pivotTable.addRowLabel(0);
   pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 1, "Sum of count");

   pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotTableStyleInfo().setName("PivotStyleMedium7");

   workbook.write(fileout);

  }

 }
}
```

Names of possible named styles can be got from `Excel`s `GUI` in `PivotTable Tools` tab - `Design`.

[image]