# how to set the pivotal table layout in java

Tags: apache-poi

is there any way to change the pivot table layout in APACHE poi lib?

we can choose the pivot table in excel, then click the any of pivot table cell
then will show a design tab in the top, we can change the layout in this table. but how can I do that in the java code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56609207/how-to-change-the-pivot-table-style-from-default-blue-to-other-colors-using-apac/56609527#56609527

Comment: this is not i wanted. I want to change the layout. not the style

Comment: Then you needs describing more accurate what exactly you wants. What exact layout setting you wants set? Also please edit your questions title. Or what exactly is a "pivtal table"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache POI: How can I set the pivot table display layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57387735/apache-poi-how-can-i-set-the-pivot-table-display-layout)