# How to Change the Default Header Background color in PIVOT Table

Tags: java, apache-poi, pivot, pivot-table

How to Change the Default Header Background color in PIVOT Table, currently its coming blue. Currently i am changing the background color from Blue to Green. But facing difficulty in achieve it.

I am used  below syntax by setting various pivot style in setName, but not find the exact colour of green. I need little more darker green which shown in expected output(which is lighter green). Please let me know how can i achieve it.

pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotTableStyleInfo().setName("");

Output which i am getting:

[image]

Below is the Output which i Want but green color should be little more darker than below (Please refer below Test Color Tab):

[image]

Green color combination which i want.

[image]

Below is the code:

```
package com.test.pivottables;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.List;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.*;

public class Testpivot8{
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
  Object[][] data = new Object[][]{
 {"AAA","BBB","CCC","DDD","EEE","FFF","GGG","HHH"}, 
  {"TOM","DUMMY","VAL","1001683","Description1","27/04/2017","CAT",780936.58},
 {"TOM","DUMMY","VAL","1001695","Description2","27/04/2017","CAT",136.28},
 {"HARRY","DUMMY1","VAL1","1001692","Description3","03/05/2017","CAT1",191468.21},
 {"HARRY","DUMMY1","VAL1","1001698","Description4","04/05/2017","CAT1",10.11}
  };

XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet) wb.createSheet("data");
XSSFSheet pivot = (XSSFSheet) wb.createSheet("summary");
for(Object[] dataRow : data){
 XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows());
 for(Object dataCell : dataRow){
 XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells());
if (dataCell instanceof String) {
 cell.setCellValue((String)dataCell);
} else if (dataCell instanceof Double) {
 cell.setCellValue((Double)dataCell);
}
 }
}

  AreaReference areaReference = new AreaReference("A1:H"+ (sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1), 
    SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);
  XSSFPivotTable pivotTable =  pivot.createPivotTable(areaReference, new CellReference("A1"), 
  sheet);
 pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().setRowHeaderCaption("AAA");

List<Integer> iterList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
iterList.add(0);
iterList.add(1);
 iterList.add(2);
iterList.add(3);
iterList.add(4);
 iterList.add(5);
 iterList.add(6);


pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().setUpdatedVersion((short)6); 

 for (Integer j : iterList) {


   pivotTable.addRowLabel(j);
   TreeSet<String> uniqueItems = new java.util.TreeSet<String>();
   for (int r = areaReference.getFirstCell().getRow()+1; r < 
   areaReference.getLastCell().getRow()+1; r++) {
   uniqueItems.add(sheet.getRow(r).getCell(j).getStringCellValue());
  }
  System.out.println(uniqueItems);
  CTPivotField ctPivotField = 
  pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(j);
 int i = 0;
   for (String item : uniqueItems) {
    ctPivotField.getItems().getItemArray(i).unsetT();
   ctPivotField.getItems().getItemArray(i).setX((long)i);
    pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields()
  .getCacheFieldArray(j)
   .getSharedItems().addNewS().setV(item);
    i++;
   }
        ctPivotField.setDefaultSubtotal(false);


         ctPivotField.setOutline(false);


    if (ctPivotField.getDefaultSubtotal()) i++; 
         for (int k = ctPivotField.getItems().getItemList().size()-1; k >= i; k--) {
         ctPivotField.getItems().removeItem(k);
        }
       ctPivotField.getItems().setCount(i);


           CTExtensionList extList = ctPivotField.addNewExtLst();
        String extXML = 
       "<ext uri=\"{2946ED86-A175-432a-8AC1-64E0C546D7DE}\""
       + " xmlns:x14=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/main\">"
    + "<x14:pivotField fillDownLabels=\"1\"/>"
     + "</ext>";
        org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject xlmObject = 
     org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject.Factory.parse(extXML);
          extList.set(xlmObject);

     }

        System.out.println("----end---");

       pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 7, "SUM");

      FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("newoutputfile.xlsx");
         wb.write(fileOut);
           fileOut.close();
          wb.close();
          }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `CellStyle`s? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38874115/java-apache-poi-how-to-set-background-color-and-borders-at-same-time

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56609207/how-to-change-the-pivot-table-style-from-default-blue-to-other-colors-using-apac/56609527#56609527. Best match of your wants might be 
`pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotTableStyleInfo().setName("PivotStyleDark7");`

Comment: Hi Axel, i tried above but it not matching the requirement. i need to have only header and Grand Total should be Dark Green. is there any ways to achieve it.

Comment: As said in my linked answer, names of possible named styles can be got from Excels GUI in `PivotTable Tools` tab - `Design`. Other default pivot table styles are not present. They would must be created then.

Comment: Thank You Axel, Currently i am using pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotTableStyleInfo().setName("PivotStyleLight21"); which is light green . As of now i am ok with this color combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Excel` pivot tables are styled using special named pivot table styles. The names of possible named styles can be got from `Excel`'s `GUI` in `PivotTable Tools` tab - `Design`. To set a style use:

```
pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotTableStyleInfo().setName("PivotStyleDark7");
```

where `PivotStyleDark7` is the name of the named style.

If none of the default styles fulfill the requirements, then new named styles must be created. In `Excel`'s `GUI` this is possible by creating a new pivot table style and format some of the given table style types, for example: header row, totals row, ...

If that shall be done using `apache poi`, then in [StylesTable](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/model/StylesTable.html) a new table style must be created. There for each table style type a table style element must point to a predefined `dxf` having the format.

```
...
  // create a new custom pivot table style
  // create dxf for each needed table style type
  STTableStyleType.Enum headerRow = STTableStyleType.HEADER_ROW;
  CTDxf headerRowDxf = createDxf(true, new byte[] {(byte)255, (byte)255, (byte)255}, new byte[] {(byte)0, (byte)80, (byte)0});
  STTableStyleType.Enum totalRow = STTableStyleType.TOTAL_ROW;
  CTDxf totalRowDxf = createDxf(true, new byte[] {(byte)255, (byte)255, (byte)255}, new byte[] {(byte)0, (byte)80, (byte)0});
  STTableStyleType.Enum firstRowSubheading = STTableStyleType.FIRST_ROW_SUBHEADING;
  CTDxf firstRowSubheadingDxf = createDxf(true, null, null);
  STTableStyleType.Enum secondRowSubheading = STTableStyleType.SECOND_ROW_SUBHEADING;
  CTDxf secondRowSubheadingDxf = createDxf(true, null, null);
  // map table style types to dxf
  Map<STTableStyleType.Enum, CTDxf> typeStyles = new HashMap<STTableStyleType.Enum, CTDxf>();
  typeStyles.put(headerRow, headerRowDxf);
  typeStyles.put(totalRow, totalRowDxf);
  typeStyles.put(firstRowSubheading, firstRowSubheadingDxf);
  typeStyles.put(secondRowSubheading, secondRowSubheadingDxf);
  // 
  createPivotTableStyle(((XSSFWorkbook)wb).getStylesSource(), "CustomPivotStyle1", typeStyles);
  pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotTableStyleInfo().setName("CustomPivotStyle1");
...
```

---

```
...
 static CTDxf createDxf(boolean fontBold, byte[] fontRGB, byte[] fillRGB) {
  CTDxf dxf = CTDxf.Factory.newInstance();
  CTFont font = dxf.addNewFont();
  if (fontBold) font.addNewB();
  if (fontRGB != null) font.addNewColor().setRgb(fontRGB);
  if (fillRGB != null) {
   CTFill fill = dxf.addNewFill();
   fill.addNewPatternFill().addNewBgColor().setRgb(fillRGB);
  }
  return dxf;
 }

 static void createPivotTableStyle(StylesTable stylesTable, String styleName, Map<STTableStyleType.Enum, CTDxf> typeStyles) {

  // get or create table styles
  CTTableStyles tableStyles = stylesTable.getCTStylesheet().getTableStyles();
  if (tableStyles == null) tableStyles = stylesTable.getCTStylesheet().addNewTableStyles();

  // add table style named as styleName
  CTTableStyle tableStyle = tableStyles.addNewTableStyle();
  tableStyle.setName(styleName);

  // set TableStyleType styles: TableStyleType -> dxf
  for (Map.Entry<STTableStyleType.Enum, CTDxf> entry : typeStyles.entrySet()) {
    STTableStyleType.Enum type = entry.getKey();
    CTDxf typeDxf = entry.getValue();
    int dxfId = stylesTable.putDxf(typeDxf);
    CTTableStyleElement tableStyleElement = tableStyle.addNewTableStyleElement();
    tableStyleElement.setDxfId(dxfId-1);
    tableStyleElement.setType(type);
  }
 }
...
```

---

Complete Example:

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.model.StylesTable;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataConsolidateFunction;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.AreaReference;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference;
import org.apache.poi.ss.SpreadsheetVersion;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import java.util.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.*;

public class Testpivot8 {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter(Locale.US);
  XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
  XSSFCellStyle dateStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
  dateStyle.setDataFormat(wb.createDataFormat().getFormat("mm/dd/yyyy"));

  Object[][] data = new Object[][]{
   {"AAA","BBB","CCC","DDD","EEE","FFF","GGG","HHH"}, 
   {"TOM","DUMMY","VAL",1001683,"Description1",new GregorianCalendar(2017, 3, 27),"CAT",780936.58},
   {"TOM","DUMMY","VAL",1001695,"Description2",new GregorianCalendar(2017, 3, 27),"CAT",136.28},
   {"HARRY","DUMMY1","VAL1",1001692,"Description3",new GregorianCalendar(2017, 4, 3),"CAT1",191468.21},
   {"HARRY","DUMMY1","VAL1",1001698,"Description4",new GregorianCalendar(2017, 4, 4),"CAT1",10.11}
  };

  XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("data");
  for(Object[] dataRow : data) {
   XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows());
   for(Object dataCell : dataRow){
    XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells());
    if (dataCell instanceof String) {
     cell.setCellValue((String)dataCell);
    } else if (dataCell instanceof Double) {
     cell.setCellValue((Double)dataCell);
    } else if (dataCell instanceof Integer) {
     cell.setCellValue((Integer)dataCell);
    } else if (dataCell instanceof GregorianCalendar) {
     cell.setCellValue((GregorianCalendar)dataCell);
     cell.setCellStyle(dateStyle);
    }
   }
  }

  XSSFSheet pivot = wb.createSheet("summary");
  int rowCount = data.length;
  int colCount = data[0].length;
  AreaReference areaReference = new AreaReference(new CellReference("A1"), new CellReference(rowCount-1, colCount-1), SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);
  XSSFPivotTable pivotTable =  pivot.createPivotTable(areaReference, new CellReference("A1"), sheet);
  pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().setRowHeaderCaption("AAA");

  List<Integer> iterList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  iterList.add(0);
  iterList.add(1);
  iterList.add(2);
  iterList.add(3);
  iterList.add(4);
  iterList.add(5);
  iterList.add(6);

  pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().setUpdatedVersion((short)6); 

  for (Integer j : iterList) {
   pivotTable.addRowLabel(j);
   TreeSet<String> uniqueItems = new java.util.TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
   for (int r = areaReference.getFirstCell().getRow()+1; r < areaReference.getLastCell().getRow()+1; r++) {
    uniqueItems.add(formatter.formatCellValue(sheet.getRow(r).getCell(j)));
   }

   System.out.println(uniqueItems);

   CTPivotField ctPivotField = pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(j);
   int i = 0;
   for (String item : uniqueItems) {
    ctPivotField.getItems().getItemArray(i).unsetT();
    ctPivotField.getItems().getItemArray(i).setX((long)i);
    pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields()
     .getCacheFieldArray(j).getSharedItems().addNewS().setV(item);
    i++;
   }
   ctPivotField.setDefaultSubtotal(false);
   ctPivotField.setOutline(false);

   if (ctPivotField.getDefaultSubtotal()) i++; 
   for (int k = ctPivotField.getItems().getItemList().size()-1; k >= i; k--) {
    ctPivotField.getItems().removeItem(k);
   }
   ctPivotField.getItems().setCount(i);

   CTExtensionList extList = ctPivotField.addNewExtLst();
   String extXML = 
      "<ext uri=\"{2946ED86-A175-432a-8AC1-64E0C546D7DE}\""
    + " xmlns:x14=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/main\">"
    + "<x14:pivotField fillDownLabels=\"1\"/>"
    + "</ext>";
   org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject xlmObject = 
   org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject.Factory.parse(extXML);
   extList.set(xlmObject);
  }

  System.out.println("----end---");

  pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 7, "SUM");

  // create a new custom pivot table style
  // create dxf for each needed table style type
  STTableStyleType.Enum headerRow = STTableStyleType.HEADER_ROW;
  CTDxf headerRowDxf = createDxf(true, new byte[] {(byte)255, (byte)255, (byte)255}, new byte[] {(byte)4, (byte)123, (byte)91});
  STTableStyleType.Enum totalRow = STTableStyleType.TOTAL_ROW;
  CTDxf totalRowDxf = createDxf(true, new byte[] {(byte)255, (byte)255, (byte)255}, new byte[] {(byte)4, (byte)123, (byte)91});
  STTableStyleType.Enum firstRowSubheading = STTableStyleType.FIRST_ROW_SUBHEADING;
  CTDxf firstRowSubheadingDxf = createDxf(true, null, null);
  STTableStyleType.Enum secondRowSubheading = STTableStyleType.SECOND_ROW_SUBHEADING;
  CTDxf secondRowSubheadingDxf = createDxf(true, null, null);
  // map table style types to dxf
  Map<STTableStyleType.Enum, CTDxf> typeStyles = new HashMap<STTableStyleType.Enum, CTDxf>();
  typeStyles.put(headerRow, headerRowDxf);
  typeStyles.put(totalRow, totalRowDxf);
  typeStyles.put(firstRowSubheading, firstRowSubheadingDxf);
  typeStyles.put(secondRowSubheading, secondRowSubheadingDxf);
  // 
  createPivotTableStyle(wb.getStylesSource(), "CustomPivotStyle1", typeStyles);
  pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotTableStyleInfo().setName("CustomPivotStyle1");

  sheet.setSelected(false);
  wb.setActiveSheet(wb.getSheetIndex(pivot));
 
  FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("newoutputfile.xlsx");
  wb.write(fileOut);
  fileOut.close();
  wb.close();
 }

 static CTDxf createDxf(boolean fontBold, byte[] fontRGB, byte[] fillRGB) {
  CTDxf dxf = CTDxf.Factory.newInstance();
  CTFont font = dxf.addNewFont();
  if (fontBold) font.addNewB();
  if (fontRGB != null) font.addNewColor().setRgb(fontRGB);
  if (fillRGB != null) {
   CTFill fill = dxf.addNewFill();
   fill.addNewPatternFill().addNewBgColor().setRgb(fillRGB);
  }
  return dxf;
 }

 static void createPivotTableStyle(StylesTable stylesTable, String styleName, Map<STTableStyleType.Enum, CTDxf> typeStyles) {

  // get or create table styles
  CTTableStyles tableStyles = stylesTable.getCTStylesheet().getTableStyles();
  if (tableStyles == null) tableStyles = stylesTable.getCTStylesheet().addNewTableStyles();

  // add table style named as styleName
  CTTableStyle tableStyle = tableStyles.addNewTableStyle();
  tableStyle.setName(styleName);

  // set TableStyleType styles: TableStyleType -> dxf
  for (Map.Entry<STTableStyleType.Enum, CTDxf> entry : typeStyles.entrySet()) {
    STTableStyleType.Enum type = entry.getKey();
    CTDxf typeDxf = entry.getValue();
    int dxfId = stylesTable.putDxf(typeDxf);
    CTTableStyleElement tableStyleElement = tableStyle.addNewTableStyleElement();
    tableStyleElement.setDxfId(dxfId-1);
    tableStyleElement.setType(type);
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the required o/p we can use

pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotTableStyleInfo().setName("PivotStyleLight21"); which is light green. In this case only header and grand total row will have light green background. Currently its satisfies my requirement.

[image]